# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to resolve assembly 'nameOfDll'

Tags: frameworks, entity

Have a Visual Studio 2010 application that use Entity Framwork to bind controls. After publishing the application to IIS 7.5, I get the following error stack trace message.

This does not happen when run local!

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to resolve assembly 'nameOfDll'.

After many hours and days of research and following all suggestions, the error still is rendered.

I made sure that all references were loaded locally and set CopyTo: to true for each reference. The only other suggestion was to set the ContextTypeName in the EntityDataSource definition. I am not certain the correct value to enter.

I have also encountered this on IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 1):

You will often get this type of error when there is a version or culture mismatch for a DLL where a specific version and/or culture is demanded.

Use the Fusion Log Viewer (Fuslogvw) to log binding errors.  NOTE: You must run it as Administrator or it will silently fail to log.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx

The output of Fuslogvw will tell you exactly what attempts were made to satisfy binding requests, and why they failed.

If this is in an environment where you can do so, stop IIS, start Fuslogvw, start Fuslogvw logging, then start IIS again and browse to the problematic website.  If you cannot stop IIS, I believe it should be sufficient to recycle the relevant application pool with Fuslogvw running and logging.